# how to get paperclip installed in rails 3 as gem

Tags: paperclip

hello i am new to ruby on rails please help me and guide me through the problem i am getting...
i want to upload profile image for ech user using paperclip
BuT I DONT KNOW HOW TO INSTALL IT
i want to install it as gem

i am doing the following thing:

```
gem install paperclip

bundle install
```

.... at the console
but on doing

```
rails generate paperclip user image
```

i am getting error could not find generator paperclip

please guide me through correct steps to upload image using paperclip as gem

Comment: which operating system u r using?

Answer (score 1):

> **Step#1**
>
> ImageMagick must be installed in the system and Paperclip must have
>   access to it. ImageMagick is a software suite to create, edit,
>   compose, or convert bitmap images. It can read and write images in a
>   variety of formats.
>
> **Step#2**

Include the paperclip gem in your Gemfile

```
gem "paperclip"
```

Then run the bundler to install the gem

```
bundle install
```

as You are new to Rails:

> It will be good if you go through this [Tutorial](http://blog.andolasoft.com/2013/01/file-uploading-through-paperclip-in-rails-3-x.html)  and usage
>   documentation under the repo of [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).